# Вывод кода HTML страницы на экран

Tags: html

Приветствую.

Если тема была - прошу перенаправить, поиск не помог. Представим, на странице нажимаем Ctrl+U, видим код, запихиваем его в БД, затем выводим. Просто, в 'pre' или      'textarea' ест-но, если внутри HTML будут закрывающие тэги, то вывод будет 'неполный'. Вопрос, как всегда предельно неадекватен: Как вывести переменную с кодом HTML для просмотра?

p.s. прошу не издеваться, чую ответ какой то очень простой, или его вообще нету

p.p.s. ну вот иногда встречаю на всяких ресурсах выводят полный код страницы, для показа, его причем можно от туда копировать манипуляцией ctrl+c/ctrl+v.. как надо - начал искать, и нет нигде

Comment: Можно вывести код как value инпута)0))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вопрос был "как вывести код страницы, а не результат его отображения", то ответ: экранируйте символы `<`и `>`, заменяя их на `&lt;` и `&gt;` соответственно.

Если вопрос был "как вывести результат отображения кода, не повредив окружающую разметку", то ответ: используйте `iframe`. Посмотрите, как это реализовано на http://jsfiddle.net, например.

Answer (score 0):

Можно в input это вставить:

```
<script>
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.value = "code";
    input.innerHTML = "code";
    document.body.appendChild(input);
```